# Sql_Srv returns just the first row

Tags: php, database, oop, sqlsrv

```
while($tab = $sMssql->fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM [Tab]")){

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($tab);
echo "</pre>";

}
```

This code returns just the first row over and over again...
But i want an array with the all rows inside.

The fetchAssoc Code:

```
public function fetchAssoc($mQuery) {
    return sqlsrv_fetch_array(sqlsrv_query($this->mSqlConnection, $mQuery), SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
}
```

Comment: If all else fails **R.T.F.M** [sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://uk3.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php) The first statement in that manual page says sqlsrv_fetch_array — Returns **>>a<<** row as an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In function fetchAssoc(), sqlsrv_fetch_array() is called only once. Call this in a loop to iterate over all records.

In your code you have while loop for query execution which is wrong. reomve that while loop and put loop inside fetchAssoc().

like :

```
$mQuery= $sMssql->fetchAssoc("SELECT * FROM [Tab]");
$result = sqlsrv_query($this->mSqlConnection, $mQuery);

while($tab = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result , SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){

    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($tab);
    echo "</pre>";

}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question.... But i get the same result...just the first entry a million times